# How can I convert a hex string in perl to ascii?

Tags: perl, hex, ascii, decode

I have an old legacy system that is pulling postgres bytea data from a database (can't change the code as it's compiled).  How do I go about converting bytea data that is in this format to an ascii string?

Here is a sample of the data:

```
my($value) = "\x46726f6d3a20224d";
```

I found this example online to decode a hex string, but the input has to start with 0x, not \x.  If I change the test string from \x to 0x then this example works however the \x is treating the next HEX 46 as a capital F as it's doing the regex match, then the rest is failing to decode.

Here is the regex I had found that works with a string starting with 0x but not \x, Is it possible to decode this type of hex string somehow?

```
$value =~ s/0x(([0-9a-f][0-9a-f])+)/pack('H*', $1)/ie;
print $value, "\n";
```

Correct output when you use 0x on the input string:

From: "M

Incorrect output (not decoded) when using \x on the input string:

F726f6d3a20224d

Cheers, Mike

Comment: Re "*`"\x46726f6d3a20224d"`*", This makes no sense. (It produces a string of length 14.) Do you mean `"\\x46726f6d3a20224d"` (which produces a string of length 18), or maybe `"\x46\x72\x6f\x6d\x3a\x20\x22\x4d"` (which produces a string of length 8)? Please clarify what input you actually have.

Comment: Its ok. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-binary.html#id-1.5.7.12.9

Comment: @gapsf That would suggest `"\\x46726f6d3a20224d"`, which produces the string `\x46726f6d3a20224d`

Comment: In literal yes but from database it should gets one backslash

Comment: pack('H*', substr($value, 2)) not needed any regexp

Comment: @Mike did you read about pack func and perl quotes? https://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut#Intel-HEX https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/perl-quoted-interpolated-and-escaped-strings/

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you actually have the string

```
\x46726f6d3a20224d
```

as produced by

```perl
my $value = "\\x46726f6d3a20224d";
```

Then all you just need to replace the `0` with `\\`.

```perl
$value =~ s/\\x(([0-9a-f][0-9a-f])+)/pack('H*', $1)/ie;
```

---

Better (less repetition and it avoids slowdowns related to ß):

```perl
$value =~ s/\\x((?:[0-9a-fA-F]{2})+)/ pack( 'H*', $1 ) /e;
```

If you expect this to be the whole string, then I'd use

```perl
$value = pack( 'H*', $value =~ s/^\\x//r );
```

The following is faster, but loses some validation:

```perl
$value = pack( 'H*', substr( $value, 2 ) );
```

Comment: my $value = '\x46726f6d3a20224d'; would be better

Comment: Awesome thanks a lot - yes I didn't realise it was actually \\, so this solution worked a treat:


$value =~ s/\\x(([0-9a-f][0-9a-f])+)/pack('H*', $1)/ie;

Comment: @gaspf, I disagree. That could easily be mistaken to mean something else, or it cause someone to think the wrong quotes were used. Those are two reasons it's *less* readable. Shorter is usually better, but not always. (If I were to use single-quotes, I'd use `'\\x46726f6d3a20224d'`. But I'd use double quotes.)